# How i can profile a python script consisting of multiple modules and classes?

Tags: python, profiling, profiler, cprofile

I want to profile my python code. My code includes several modules where each module is a class with several functions. I am using eclipse PyDev as IDE. I have read a few QA about timeit and cprofile but using these profilers are a bit hard when you have classes that make use of other classes and there are chain calls through them.

I was just wondering if there is a profiler like Java profilers which can show me where i need to optimize my code (i was thinking of multithreading some parts of my code but i want to make sure which parts need it).

Comment: People love graphs. They're great eye-candy. [*Flame-graphs*](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/) are another one. But if what you want is speed, [*here's how I do it*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pycallgraph** is a beautiful tool for profiling python code http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/

Comment: I tested pycallgraph. It is very easy and indeed a great tool for profiling python code.